# How to smooth a mesh border?

Tags: modeling

Well … I join two meshes into one, but the borders are not smooth, how can I make an soft transition for the borders?[image]

Comment: Joining is not welding, it's just combining data under one name, one set of transforms.. maybe show the topology of the parts by checking 'wire' in the object>display panel, to get some suggestions.,,

Comment: I'm new in the blender, so getting into the wire mode did not make a difference to me

Comment: Sure. Displaying the wires wouldn't make a difference. But putting up a picture with the wire (topology) showing might help others to make suggestions about how to fix your model :)

Comment: first things first try using W -> Remove Doubles. I pray that to every beginner and most of the time it is the magic button which solves all problems. In your case though there might be different materials at the joint as well, that will make everything a little more tricky

Comment: Thanks for the help, here's the image, I think it's the wire you want, sorry if it's wrong, I really do not know much about the blender, and especially about modeling

http://prntscr.com/lsga47